# How to have the BLE running even when the Mac goes to sleep?

Tags: ios, macos, core-bluetooth

I am new to developing apps for Mac OS and currently developing an app where i would like to have the BLE running even when the Mac goes to sleep mode.
Basically i want the Mac app to be connected to the peripheral devices if the peripheral is in range if not they will be disconnected but in a event when the peripheral comes back in the range i want the mac app to connect to it again.

Is there a way to do this? I have developed a few apps on iOS and i know there is a background mode in iOS but obviously we don't have it in  Mac apps which makes sense but is there something that we can use to keep the app running when the device goes to sleep?

Appreciate your time to look into this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you can't.

Background mode is different to sleep mode.  When an iOS device is in low power mode the display is off and various other hardware is shut down to save battery, but it is still executing code.

When a Mac is in sleep mode, execution is suspended, so your app cannot run.  Apple's PowerNap capabilities would, in theory, allow you to do something, but there are no public APIs for it.

Of course your app keeps running while the Mac is asleep in the sense that when the Mac resumes from sleep the user doesn't need to take any action to relaunch your app like they might have to on iOS, but you can't actually execute code while the Mac is in sleep mode.

The best you can do is have your app reconnect if the device is in range when the Mac wakes up.